# How to set HLSL parameter of type float2?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna, hlsl

I was wondering how one can set a parameter `p` of type `float2` in an HLSL shader effect `e` using C# ?

```
e.Parameters["p.x"].SetValue(1); 
e.Parameters["p.y"].SetValue(2);
```

seems to not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
e.Parameters["p"].SetValue(new Vector2(1, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

When using properties that expose struct types, if one wants to update some parts without updating the other, it is frequently necessary to use a pattern like:

```
var temp = thing.SomeProperty;
temp.X = 1;
thing.SomeProperty = temp;
```

In your particular case, it looks like you want to rewrite all components of the struct in question; if that's the case, you may simply construct a new struct instance and store that; there's no reason to read out the old one first.  Although some people may prefer the format

```
var temp = thing.SomeProperty;
temp.X = new Vector2(1, temp.Y);
thing.SomeProperty = temp;
```

I don't like it so much, because it makes it harder to tell which fields are or are not being modified, especially if there exist any constructor overloads which don't require the specification of all field values.